# checking if Sign/Encrypt are checked in the Delivery Options of an outgoing email

Tags: c++, lotus-notes

I'm writing a C++ plugin to Lotus Notes. when the user sends an email, I would like to know whether the Sign/Encrypt options are checked in the Delivery Options of the outgoing email.

I tried to use NSFNoteIsSignedOrSealed, supplying the HANDLE to the outgoing note, but it returns false even when Sign/Encrypt are checked. (I guess because the email is not yet encrypted/signed when the plugin is called). I saw in the header file stdnames.h the defines ITEM_NAME_NOTE_FORCESIGN and ITEM_NAME_NOTE_FORCESEAL, which sound promising. how do I check for the value of those items using the HANDLE to the note?

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little surprised that you're writing a Notes plugin module without having learned how to read a text item value from a document, or at least without having learned where in the documentation you can go to find out how.  The code below is literally just a cut/paste from the Notes C API Users Guide, Chapter 5-3, Reading Documents, except that I've taken the liberty of changing the field name from the constant used in the sample code on that page to match one of the two fields that you're looking for.

```
/* Look for the Sign field within this note. */
  field_found = NSFItemIsPresent (note_handle,
                ITEM_NAME_NOTE_FORCESIGN,
                strlen (ITEM_NAME_NOTE_FORCESIGN));

  /* If Sign field is there, get contents and print it.
   If the Sign field is not there, print a message.*/
  if (field_found)
   {
   field_len = NSFItemGetText (note_handle, 
                ITEM_NAME_NOTE_FORCESIGN,
                field_text,
                sizeof (field_text));
   printf ("ITEM_NAME_NOTE_FORCESIGN field is: %s\n", field_text);
   }
  else
   printf ("ITEM_NAME_NOTE_FORCESIGN field not found.\n");
```